# Accent error on OpenWrt 12.09?

Tags: locale, openwrt

```
[user@localhost ~] ssh -x -a root@192.168.1.1
BusyBox v1.19.4 (2013-03-14 11:28:31 UTC) built-in shell (ash)
 -----------------------------------------------------
 ATTITUDE ADJUSTMENT (12.09, r36088)
 -----------------------------------------------------
root@ROUTER:~# touch 'árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép'
root@ROUTER:~# ls -la
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Aug 31 11:26 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 ..
drwx------    2 root     root             0 Aug 15 16:09 .ssh
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Aug 31 11:26 ????rv??zt??r?? t??k??rf??r??g??p
root@ROUTER:~# ls -la áárvíztűrő\ tükörfúrógép 
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Aug 31 11:26 ????rv??zt??r?? t??k??rf??r??g??p
root@ROUTER:~# rm áárvíztűrő\ tükörfúrógép
```

**Q:** Why? The accent handling was ok a few versions before.. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: the same problem occurs if I put this in cron.

Comment: Please paste output of `locale` or (if not available) `set | grep LC_` and `set | grep LANG` both from within the router shell and from your workstation.

Comment: Bug reproduced here too.  Locale isn't installed by default.  There are no `LC_` or `LANG`variables on the router either.  My workstation locale is `en_GB.utf8`.  At a guess, there was no "accent handling" at all before, but now `ls` has been improved not to dump 8-bit characters to a terminal with unknown locale.  Or maybe it's a true regression in the ssh server (dropbear).

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ash`, the default busybox shell which does not support unicode fonts. See [here](https://bugs.maemo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7592) for a bug report.

The only workaround will probably be to run another shell, like `bash` or `zsh` instead of `ash`. If those are installed, you can use `chsh` to change your default shell.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you have a file with another fonts such as:

```
mohsen@debian:~/test/locale$ touch پخاسثد
mohsen@debian:~/test/locale$ ls
پخاسثد
```

But your `terminal` configured as can't show your language, check the following variable:

```
mohsen@debian:~/test/locale$ echo $LANG
en_US.utf8
```

You should can support `UTF-8`.